# RDLC report exporting to pdf with Page number in footer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I am rendering an rdlc report to the client directly, tried adding the page number using the code below in the footer

```
=Globals.PageNumber & " of " & Globals.TotalPages
```

I am getting #Error when the report is rendered as pdf on the client. Need assitance to resolve the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
=Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages
```

Comment: still the #Error is rendering instead of Page number

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but for me it was a security issue.

I checked the warnings received from render method.

```
Warning[] warnings; //<-- Check these errors

var reportData = localReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
    out fileNameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings);
```

Found the following error:

```
The Value expression for the textrun ‘PageNumber.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[2]’ contains an error: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

Solution was to add the following line before rendering:

```
localReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet.Copy());
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved.
I started to create another page but ended up deleting the reference Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms and readded the correct version back 
I think that solved my problem. Hurray.